# What is the default web server in visual studio 2015 community?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I want to run a asp.net project . I have imported as website in visual studio community version 2015 and read the documentation to run the project .

I have put several dlls in winsysdir (C:/windows/system32) . In the documentation the following text is written :

```
2. Local Security Settings
The SecuSearch SDK Pro setup automatically configures the local security setting that is required to run the
SecuSearch engine. However, if setup fails for any reason, you may need to configure it manually.
1. Run “Local Security Policy” from Control Panel / Administrative Tools.
2. Look into the tree name “User Rights Assignment” under Security Settings / Local Policies.
3. Select “Lock pages in memory” and open its Properties. Refer to the picture below.
4. Add the “Administrators” group or specific users by selecting “Add User of Group…”. Only users with this
privilege can start the SecuSearch engine.
5. After updating this setting, restart the system to apply the changes.
```

For web server :

```
For Web Environment
For web environment, running the SecuSearch engine in IIS, you should specify additional user or group
settings for “Lock pages in memory” as shown above. Also, for Windows 7, the IIS_IUSRS group is required;
for Windows 2003, IIS_WPG is required.
```

To do the task for web server I need to configure IIS server . But I do not know which IIS server is run by visual studio .

When I run this asp.net project , I have the following error .

```
ERROR: Application_Start: SSAPP_Initialize: 601 / You need to restart the application pool (or IIS) before retry.
```

How can I remove this error ? How can I specify additional user or group
settings for “Lock pages in memory” in IIS server ? Please help me .

Comment: Visual Studio comes with IIS Express (10, for VS 2015). IIS Express doesn't have all the features of IIS.

Comment: How to remove this error ? "ERROR: Application_Start: SSAPP_Initialize: 601 / You need to restart the application pool (or IIS) before retry."

Comment: Assuming you're debugging/launching the app from Visual Studio, it gets restarted whenever you debug. The problem you're probably running into is that IIS Express isn't built for whatever feature your dlls are trying to leverage. It's called "Express" for a reason.

Comment: The documentation you pasted clearly asks for full IIS which you should enable via control panel on Windows. Then run VS as administrator and you can set the project to use full IIS instead of IIS Express.

Comment: I have start the project with full IIS . But the same error I am facing . ERROR: Application_Start: SSAPP_Initialize: 601 / You need to restart the application pool (or IIS) before retry.